# Rules of Matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a quick question about a proof I saw. The statement was:

$$\frac{1}{2} x^T 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 \end{bmatrix} x - \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} x^T x = \frac{1}{2} x^T \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{8} - 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 + \sqrt{8} \end{bmatrix} x $$
Now, I see that what's happening here is you're taking out the common factor of $x^T x$ but if we do this:
$$\frac{1}{2} x^T( 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}  - \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} ) x $$
But I now have a case of scalar subtracted from a matrix. To get the correct answer we would want to do:
$$\frac{1}{2} x^T( 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}  -  \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} \end{bmatrix}) x $$
But why couldn't this operation mean:
$$\frac{1}{2} x^T( 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}  - \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} & \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} \\
\frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} & \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} \end{bmatrix} ) x $$
At what point was I supposed to put that identity matrix in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why couldn't this operation mean..

Because $\frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} x^T x = \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} x^T I x$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. So when you factor, you get
$$\frac{1}{2} x^T 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 \end{bmatrix} x - \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} x^T x = x^T (\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{3 - \sqrt{8}}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}) x$$

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$x^Tx=x^T I x$$